# how to webs service dbConnection.vb to change to c# code?

Tags: c#, web-services, sqlconnection

hi i newbiest in c#, i have to write webs service(btw business to business) in c#

but i normally do in vb, so i am not sure how it look like in C# the dbconnection
. If can show me some link that will help me out in doing the webs service ( btw business to business)
Now i have connect the sql database in the server to the web service
this is my dbconnection.vb, so how to change it to c sharp, hope anyone can show me how the code look like in c#

```
    Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class dbconnection
    Function getConnection() As SqlConnection
        Dim dbConn As SqlConnection

        dbConn = New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|delivery.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True")

        Return dbConn
    End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

The one-to-one implementation looks like following:

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
public class DbConnection
{
    public SqlConnection getConnection()
    {
        SqlConnection dbConn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|delivery.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
        return dbConn;
    }
}
```

However, I cannot say it follows best-practices. Consider implementing `IDisposable` to free unmanaged resources correctly:

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System;
public class DbConnection : IDisposable
{
    public SqlConnection DbConn { get; private set; }

    public DbConnection()
    {
        DbConn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|delivery.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (DbConn.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed) {
            DbConn.Close();
        }
        DbConn.Dispose();
    }
}
```

It's usage looks like

```
using(DbConnection myClassInstance = new DbConnection()) {
    SqlConnection connection = myClassInstance.DbConn;
}
```

Comment: wad do you mean one to one? or not i shld just ask you if i want to create a website, how am i goin to connect to the server database which i add the server database into a connection in visual studio

Comment: By one-to-one I mean it's the same code as yours, ported as-is to C#.

Comment: oh okay so do you know how i can connect the database into the web service